# Is there a built-in way to compare two iterators?

Tags: iterator, rust

I've written the following function to compare two iterators, element-by-element. However, it would be great if I could just reuse something in the standard library.

```
fn iter_eq<A, B, T, U>(mut a: A, mut b: B) -> bool
where
    A: Iterator<Item = T>,
    B: Iterator<Item = U>,
    T: PartialEq<U>,
{
    loop {
        match (a.next(), b.next()) {
            (Some(ref a), Some(ref b)) if a == b => continue,
            (None, None) => return true,
            _ => return false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter();
    let b = vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter();

    assert!(iter_eq(a, b));
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's [`Iterator::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq) as well as various other comparison functions ([`lt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.lt), [`ne`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.ne), etc.).

Answer (score 5):

The third party crate [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) has [`itertools::equal`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/fn.equal.html) and [`itertools::assert_equal`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/fn.assert_equal.html).